# Setting up Steam on Kubuntu 18.10 to a non-/home folder?

Tags: security, games, directory, steam

Please tell me: is there any known way to install Steam to a NON-/home folder, WITHOUT needing to resort to moving things later post-install, and making symbolic links?

So far the only solution i knew that worked is linking from somewhere in my /home folder, to a subfolder under /usr.

it might not be secure but it used to avoid a lot of hassle later on.  This is the way i used to set it up on Debian Stretch and upward ... BUT back then (in debian) i had kdesu and kdesudo facilities, and i just the other day found out that Ubuntu removed "gksu" type commands in favor of gedit admin:/// structures :(

sigh

is there a better more "official" way, to install Steam to a non-/home folder?

I agree with people over on the Steam forums ( https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864961721717298260/ ) that a more logical and secure idea would be to have Steam itself just run as it's own local user account, say in its own group, etc... with it's own setup home folder, etc... but apparently Valve does not care?

Comment: Is this just for the size of games that you have in your Steam library that you want them on a different mount or drive?  If so, you can still install Steam like normal, but then change the location for install before you complete the first install steps where it ask you to choose the library.  I run mine all on another shared drive that is NTFS and it works great.

Comment: yes. i do not like having a huge home folder. i am tired of the only solution being to make shared links of the 1 tiny small home folder to a larger folder on say, /usr. I know i can add a second folder and make it default, say, under /usr, but allllllllllll the non-game-app-data for Steam is all still stored under my own home folder! :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I very highly doubt that anyone here is going to be able to help you on that one.  This sounds more like a feature request that you will have to go to Steam themselves to fix to allow you to choose where you will install Steam itself if you don't want the links.

Comment: i just want a better way to install steam that is NOT under my /home directory.  i do not think Valve cares or listens and i was hoping someone else had a solution because big companies like Valve cannot be trusted nor do they care about their customers :( i prefer independent people.

Comment: If their software was OpenSource then their installation could be changed to match the way you would like it.  Unfortunately, it is not OpenSource so there is no way that we could be able to do it.